# multiprocessing.dummy why AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dummy'

Tags: python, module, multiprocessing, python-import

I met a strange thing in Python:

```
>>> import multiprocessing

>>> thread_pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dummy'
```

However, when I try the following:

```
>>> from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
>>> ThreadPool()
<multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool object at 0x7faf9308d4a8>
```

and

```
>>> import multiprocessing.dummy
>>> multiprocessing.dummy.Pool()
<multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool object at 0x7faf9308d2e8>
```

Everything is OK. 
I know the difference between `import xxx` and `from xxx import`, I wonder why It raise AttributeError. **My question is why I couldn't use `multiprocessing.dummy` after `import multiprocessing`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multiprocessing.dummy` package is not imported in `multiprocessing.__init__.py`. Hence,

```
>>> import multiprocessing

>>> thread_pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool()
```

does not work. Form the docstring:

```
# This package is intended to duplicate the functionality (and much of
# the API) of threading.py but uses processes instead of threads.  A
# subpackage 'multiprocessing.dummy' has the same API but is a simple
# wrapper for 'threading'.
```

I guess the subpackage has intentionally been *hidden* to prevent people from accidentaly using it.

Comment: I try to add `'dummy'` into `__all__` in `multiprocessing/__init__.py`, `multiprocessing.dummy` still doesn't work.